# How do I read into a .txt and extract a certain string corresponding to a found string?

Tags: bash, terminal, grep, txt

A folder contains a README.txt and several dicom files named emr_000x.sx (where x are numerical values). In the README.txt are different lines, one of which contains the characters "xyz" and a corresponding emr_000x.sx in the line.

I would like to: read into the .txt, identify which line contains "xyz", and extract the emr_000x.sx from that line only.
For reference, the line in the .txt is formatted in this way:

```
A:emr_000x.sx,  B:00001, C:number, D(characters)string_string_number_**xyz**_number_number
```

I think using grep might be helpful, but am not familiar enough to bash coding myself. Does anyone know how to solve this? Many thanks!

Comment: Does `grep -F '_xyz_' README.txt | grep -o 'emr_000[0-9]\.s[0-9]'` work?

Comment: are there any other commands that need to follow this? this on its own didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to match fields on you csv:

```
awk -F, '$4 ~ "xyz" {sub(/^A:/, "", $1); print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I like `sed` for this sort of thing.

```
 sed -nE '/xyz/{ s/^.*A:([^,]+),.*/\1/; p; }' README.txt
```

This says, "On lines where you see `xyz` replace the whole line with the non-commas between `A:` and a comma, then print the line."

`-n` is `n`o printing unless I say so. (`p` means `p`rint.)
`-E` just means to use `E`xtended regexes.

`/xyz/{...}` means "on lines where you see `xyz` do the stuff between the curlies."
`s/^.*A:([^,]+),.*/\1/` will `s`ubstitute the matched part (which should be the whole line) with just the part between the parens.